# How to execute a function after the previous has finished using Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype, fade, scriptaculous

In my example, I want to remove a class name from one element only after a fade out of another element is completed. Here is my code thus far:

```
    $('search-box').observe('click', function(e) {
        $('question-box').fade();
        $('faq-box').removeClassName('left-60');
    });
```

As you can see these will execute one after the other, but as the element fades out slowly it will look like its executing at the same time. I want to wait to the fade completes before I remove the class name.

Any suggestions? Would a callback work here? Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Ben

Comment: Not using JQuery, using Prototype.js [link]http://prototypejs.org/

Comment: I don't see `fade()` in http://api.prototypejs.org/

Comment: Are you using an add-on library that adds this effect?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. [Link] http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/effect-fade/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `afterFinish` callback to execute the function after the fade is done:

```
$('question-box').fade({
    afterFinish: function() {
        $('faq-box').removeClassName('left-60');
    }
});
```

See the [Core Effects Overview](http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/core-effects/) for the options common to all the script.aculo.us effects.